# Get ComboBox Selection value + karate robot

Tags: karate, robot

I have a combobox control which has empty value while loading. I need to verify no selection while loading. So the SelectionSelection is the property changing while clicking on the dropdown. The following line is printing some thing like 'native@0x17dd30fb5c0'

```
 * def select = locate('#DefaultDropdown').property('SelectionSelection').toString()
 * print select
```

How can I verify the default selection in karate robot?